# Wix - Setting service startup type using a property, property not recognized?

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

Is there a way to set service startup type by using a property? WiX is not recognizing the property for some reason. This shouldn't be hard, but I am having trouble making it work.

```
<Property Id="StartUpType" Value="auto" />
...
...
<Component Id="..." Guid="...">
<File Id='...' Name='...' DiskId='1' Source='...'  KeyPath='yes'/>
<ServiceInstall
    Id="..."
    Type="ownProcess"
    Name="..."
    DisplayName="..."
    Description="..."
    Start="[StartUpType]"
    Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]"
    Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]"
    ErrorControl="normal"
    Vital="yes"
    Interactive="no" />
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl1" Stop="uninstall" Remove="both" Name="..." Wait="yes" />
```

More precisely, this line

```
Start="[StartUpType]"
```

isn't recognizing my porperty.

Error: The ServiceInstall/@Start attribute's value, '[StartUpType]', is not one of the legal options: 'auto', 'demand', or 'disabled'.

Any suggestion to make it recognize my property? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things,  only columns in Windows Installer of type Formatted can use [Property] substituions are runtime.  The only work around for this is 2 components with different implementations of the ServiceInstall table where the components have mutually exclusive conditions so that only 1 gets installed.

Also, only public properties [PROPERTY] marked with the Secure attribute (aka secure custom public property) can be relied on for substitution as regulator public and private properties don't persist from the UI to Execute sequences.

The preprocessor route will only work if you want to build similar but different MSI's. ( Build time variation points. )  If you want an Install time variation point you'll have to go the mutually exclusive component route or the harder dynamically emmited ServiceInstall table route using custom actions that leverage SQL Temporary Tables.   ( Much harder... )

Comment: Thanks. For me I have a dialogue of radio buttons that change the service startup type. So I think I'll be going with the 2-component route.

Comment: This will require either having two different .exe's for different startup types, or same file installed by two different components, both of which seem bad